# Mat-table with headers in two rows, using Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8, mat-table

I'm showing information in a table using mat-table. I have something like this:

[material table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYXsq.png)

with this HTML:

```
  <div class="container">
   <div class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <table #dataTable mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
      <ng-container class="ng-hide" matColumnDef="$key">
        <th class="ng-hide" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ID del Paciente</th>
        <td class="ng-hide" mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.$key}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="nombre_paciente">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Nombre </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.nombre_paciente}}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="apellido_paciente">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Apellido </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.apellido_paciente}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="dni">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> DNI </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.dni}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="fecha_nacimiento">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Fecha de Nacimiento </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.fecha_nacimiento | date: "dd/MM/yyyy" }</td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="obra_social">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Obra Social </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.obra_social}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="numero_os">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Número de Obra Social </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.numero_os}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="telefono">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Número de teléfono </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.telefono}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="telefono_contacto">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Teléfono de Contacto </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.telefono_contacto}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="accion">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index;">
          <button mat-raised-button color="primary" class="push-right"
            [routerLink]="['/PacienteEdita/', element.$key]">Editar</button>
          <button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="deletePaciente(i, element)">Eliminar</button>
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this TS:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Paciente } from './../../shared/paciente';
import { MatTableDataSource, MatTable } from '@angular/material';
import { PacienteService } from './../../shared/paciente.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-pacientes-detalle',
  templateUrl: './pacientes-detalle.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pacientes-detalle.component.css']
})
export class PacientesDetalleComponent implements OnInit {
  id: any;
  element: Paciente;
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Paciente[]>;
  displayedColumns: any[] = [
    '$key',
    'nombre_paciente',
    'apellido_paciente',
    'dni',
    'fecha_nacimiento',
    'obra_social',
    'numero_os',
    'telefono',
    'telefono_contacto',
    'accion'
  ];
  @ViewChild('dataTable',{ static:false }) dataTable: MatTable<any>;
  constructor(
    private actRoute: ActivatedRoute, 
    private pacienteApi: PacienteService
    ) { 
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.id = this.actRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.pacienteApi.GetPaciente(this.id).valueChanges().subscribe(data => {
      /* Data table */
      this.element = data;
      this.element.$key = this.id;
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Paciente[]>([data]);
    })
  }
}
```

I'm trying to get, using mat-table and angular 8, something like this:

[table without material](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RswCg.png)

The problem is i can't make it work with displayedColumns. I've tried to use two different displayed columns, but it didn't work for me.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the answers and help. Finally I solved this by creating a common table and adding material CSS to it!

HTML

```
 <div class="container">
  <div class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <table class="mat-table">
      <tr class="mat-header-row">
        <th class="mat-header-cell">Nombre</th>
        <th class="mat-header-cell">Apellido</th>
        <th class="mat-header-cell">DNI</th>
        <th class="mat-header-cell">Fecha de Nacimiento</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="mat-row">
        <td class="mat-cell">{{element.nombre_paciente}}</td>
        <td class="mat-cell">{{element.apellido_paciente}}</td>
        <td class="mat-cell">{{element.dni}}</td>
        <td class="mat-cell">{{element.fecha_nacimiento | date: "dd/MM/yyyy"}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="mat-header-row">
        <th class="mat-header-cell">Obra Social</th>
        <th class="mat-header-cell">Número de Obra Social</th>
        <th class="mat-header-cell">Número de Teléfono</th>
        <th class="mat-header-cell">Número de Contácto</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="mat-row">
        <td class="mat-cell">{{element.obra_social}}</td>
        <td class="mat-cell">{{element.numero_os}}</td>
        <td class="mat-cell">{{element.telefono}}</td>
        <td class="mat-cell">{{element.telefono_contacto}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4" style="width: 100%;">
        <div>
          <button mat-button matTooltip="Ver la ficha del paciente" (click)="fichaDialog()">Ficha</button>
          <button mat-button matTooltip="Ver observaciones del paciente" (click)="observacionesDialog()">Observaciones</button>
          <button mat-button matTooltip="Ver tratamientos del paciente"(click)="tratamientosDialog()">Tratamientos</button>
          <button mat-button matTooltip="Ver turnos del paciente" (click)="turnosDialog()">Turnos</button>
        </div>
      </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="justify-content: center;">
        <td colspan="4" style="width: 100%;">
        <div class="footer">
          <button mat-raised-button  color="primary" class="push-right" style="width: 83.11px;"
            [routerLink]="['/PacienteEdita/',id]">Editar</button>
          <button mat-raised-button  color="warn" (click)="deletePaciente(id, element)">Eliminar</button>
        </div>
      </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
table.mat-table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

tr.mat-header-row {
  height: 56px;
}

tr.mat-row, tr.mat-footer-row {
  height: 48px;
  text-align: center;
}

th.mat-header-cell {
  text-align: center;
  width: 25%;
}

th.mat-header-cell, td.mat-cell, td.mat-footer-cell {
  padding: 0;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
}

th.mat-header-cell:first-child, td.mat-cell:first-child, td.mat-footer-cell:first-child {
  padding-left: 24px;
  width: 25%;
}

th.mat-header-cell:last-child, td.mat-cell:last-child, td.mat-footer-cell:last-child {
  padding-right: 24px;
}

.footer{    
  align-items: flex-end;
  padding: 8px;
  padding-top: 12px;
}
.buttonsTr{
  width: 100% !important;
}
.buttonsDiv{
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

I hope this could be useful to anyone!!

Comment: can you add an example of your solution to your answer? I am trying to do something similar and that would be a good help. And i'm sure it will help others, too.

Comment: @osiris I updated the answer.  I hope it is of use !

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help.

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="nombre_paciente">
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> 
       <div class="inner-col-header">Nombre<div>
       <div class="inner-col-data">{{element.nombre_paciente}}<div>
       <div class="inner-col-header">Obra Social<div>
       <div class="inner-col-data">{{element.obra_social}}<div>
    </td>
</ng-container>
```

You can format your data with both classes inner-col-data and inner-col-header and get rid of not used columns ( Obra Social in this case)

Comment: Good idea, but its not working for me. It only shows the first data (in this case Nombre), but the second header and data is not showing (Obra Social). Errors shown on console:

ERROR Error: Missing definitions for header, footer, and row; cannot determine which columns should be rendered.

Comment: Ok. Solved previous error of missing definitions. Now, it only shows the first row of headers and data, but not the second ones. No errors shown on console